# ROW_NUMBER, RANK, or DENSE_RANK to have the SAME order number if there are rows with same values

Tags: sqlite, row-number, dense-rank

*PROBLEM*
Form a scoreboard with position number, player name and best score. If two players have the same score, they share the position and the names are in alpabetical order. (See example.)

I have two tables

```
INSERT INTO players (id,name) VALUES (1, Uolevi),(2,Maija),(3,Liisa),(4,Kaaleppi),(5,Kotivalo);
```

```
INSERT INTO results (id, player_id, score) VALUES (1, 1, 100), (2, 2, 200), (3, 3, 200), (4, 4, 100), (5, 5, 50);
```

The expected result is:

| Order | Name | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Liisa | 200 |
| 1 | Maija | 200 |
| 3 | Kaaleppi | 100 |
| 3 | Uolevi | 100 |
| 5 | Kotivalo | 50 |

Please **look carefully** at the order number. Because there are 2 rows with order number 1, the next order number will be **3**, instead of **2**.

Comment: It seems that you already know about window functions (you name some of them in the question's title). Did you try them? Take some time to read about them: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-window-functions/ and try something.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```sql
WITH
    places AS (
        SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC, name) AS place, name, score
        FROM players
        JOIN results ON players.id = results.player_id
    )
SELECT first_value(place) OVER (PARTITION BY score ORDER BY place) AS place, name, score
FROM places ORDER BY score DESC, name;
```

See the [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2nga4FQKhXUwSpJ8GfwQKo/1).

Answer (score 0):

You need rank() to keep ranking if there is a tie. dense_rank() when you don't need gaps between ranks.

```sql
select rank() over (order by r.score desc)       as order1,
       dense_rank() over (order by r.score desc) as order2,
       p.name,
       r.score
  from players p
  join results r
    on p.id = r.player_id
 order by r.score desc, p.name;
```

Outcome (include both rank() and dense_rank() for your reference).

```
| order1 | order2 | name      | score |
+--------+--------+-----------+-------+
| 1      | 1      | Liisa     |   200 |
| 1      | 1      | Maija     |   200 |
| 3      | 2      | Kaaleppi  |   100 |
| 3      | 2      | Uolevi    |   100 |
| 5      | 3      | Kotivalo  |    50 |
```